# Maximum update depth exceeded with recompose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

i saw several topics talking about this common mistake, but i didn't find nothing related to the use of recompose.

***Context***

I've this `withStateHandler`

```
withStateHandlers(
    {
      bookingValidation: false,
    },
    {
      setBookingValidation: ({ bookingValidation }) => () => ({
        bookingValidation: !bookingValidation,
      }),
    },
  ),
```

and i've this `lifeCycle`

```
lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const { getFamily } = this.props;
      getFamily();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
      const { formValues } = prevProps;
      const { setBookingValidation } = this.props;
      const {
        locationId,
        specialityId,
        serviceId,
        cancellationDetails,
        personId,
        date,
      } = formValues;

      const allFormValuesSelected = !!(
        locationId &&
        specialityId &&
        serviceId &&
        cancellationDetails &&
        personId &&
        date
      );

      if (allFormValuesSelected) setBookingValidation();
    },
  }),
```

it's a simple validation, when i've all the selectedValues, the state of bookingValidation will change on `true` and you will be able to click on a button.

***Problem***

When you enter in this if `if (allFormValuesSelected) setBookingValidation();` the maximum update depth exceeded because of the function `setBookingValidation()`

***Question***
How can i avoid this behavior ?
There is a way to maintain this function ?

Comment: Your code is fine, just make sure `setBookingValidation()` is not called in an infinite loop. The simplest solution is to have another state flag and update that after the first call for `setBookingValidation()` and before you call it again in `componentWillReceiveProps()` you can verify if the execution is for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `setBookingValidation()` changes property value and calls `componentWillReceiveProps`. And you got an infinite loop of calls.

If you want to perform form validation, you should move that functionality into a separate [withHandlers()](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withhandlers) method and call `onChange` event.

Comment: could you give me an example ? i tried to follow your advices and write some code, but I received the same error. 

If you want i can update the question